# create jar with META-INF\services for Jboss module extension

Tags: java, maven, jboss, javac

I wish to implement an interface, to create a jar to put it in the deployment folder in JBoss.
I only have one .java file.
However I can't get any jar working.

I could not find any doc on how to build the Jar.
I'm willing to use any tool, i tried an InterliJ Artefact (was the whole project).
I tried javac (using the InteliJ artefact for libraries), then jar, then adding the file  /META-INF/services/org.[myinterface] manually

I found the two posts
[Adding META-INF\services\javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631147/adding-meta-inf-services-javax-xml-parsers-saxparserfactory-to-jar)
and
[Create META-INF/services file with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056142/create-meta-inf-services-file-with-maven)
But none of these give me enough precision.

I don't think it's helping, because I know my Jar has en issue, but here is the error in the deployment :

> org.my-class-to-implement: Provider org.my-implementation not found

If someone has a link to an existing project that can generate the correct jar, or a procedure to create it, that could save my day

Question that could help me :
Is it ok to manually add the /META-INF/services/ file ?
If there is a package name, should i mention it somewhere ?

Thanks for any help, if i find the correct procedure in the meantime, i'll post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it using an artefact in Intellij
It worked once i put the Abstract class (the one i whished to implement) in the module

step to follow :

- create a module in Intellij (i copyed an existing example)
- Add the class i wished to implement
- Put the implementation of the class
- In src/main/ressources/META-inf/org.my.interface.to.implement put the name of my class : 
  org.my.implmentation
- Create an artefact of the module (you can follow this guide [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly))
- The jar can deployed in the JBOSS deploy directory

I removed the pom in the commentary to avoid confusion.
I can send you the jar or the module per mail if that can help, just ask

Answer (score 0):

Use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to make a jar with `mvn package` or use Eclipse to create a `Runnable jar`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do i include the file /META-INF/services/ in the jar ? 
I create a new mvn project with just one class, then do some modification on the project ? 
Or do i do it manually after the jar creation ?

Comment: There are configuration in Maven to add what you want to your jar, read the doc

Comment: Add your pom.xml to post

Comment: When i wish to build the mvn project, i got the same error :
`no service provider org.my-class-to-implement`
i must be missing something, but i don't know what.
Thanks again for your answer, that's what i asked for in the first time, an example or a procedure.
I'll keep searching for answers

Comment: Add it to the main post for best reading, add `Edit: Add Maven to project -> pom.xml` and the content of the pom.xml, thanks

Comment: Do you think i still should put the pom.xml ?
it's 121 lines, and i don't think it's going to help someone much

Comment: Give it via pastebin/hastbin

Comment: Use [Shade library](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: I managed to create the jar two days ago, the blocking point was that i had to include the interface in the module (just importing it using imports was not enough). I don't need this shade library. Thanks for the answer anyway